# a confusion about nodemanager and app master roles in yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

can some one please explain the role of node manager and app master in YARN.
from what I read, node manager is responsible of launching and tracking tasks in a node, and app master is responsible for  launching tasks in a container and negotiating resource with the resource manager.
I'm not sure if these information are correct or not, please correct me if I'm wrong.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudera blog has multiple articles explaining this. refer the link below:
https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-1/

Comment: a very good article, thank you. there is one thing that I didn't understand well, in the article they say that `NodeManager is a worker daemon that launches and tracks processes` which kind of process they are talking about ?

Comment: NodeManager is primarily limited to managing abstract containers i.e. only processes corresponding to a container and not concerning itself with per-application state management like MapReduce tasks. It includes keeping up-to date with the ResourceManager (RM), overseeing containers’ life-cycle management; monitoring resource usage (memory, CPU) of individual containers, tracking node-health, log’s management and auxiliary services which may be exploited by different YARN applications.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The per-application ApplicationMaster is, in effect, a framework specific library and is tasked with negotiating resources from the ResourceManager and working with the NodeManager(s) to execute and monitor the tasks.

Check the [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) for more details.